# Is there a way to go directly to a JSON node using ruby and a location?

Tags: json, ruby

I have the following code:

```
json_string = '{
  "EmployeeName": {
    "FirstName": "Lex",
    "LastName": "Sharma"
  }
}'

final_data = JSON.parse(json_string)
```

And I have a variable that is read in with the value of the given field, Ie:

`location = ['EmployeeName', 'FirstName']`

So I would like to retrieve the value somehow in one line preferably, something like

`value = final_data[location]`

Unfortunately even Ruby isn't this flexible, is there something wrong with my syntax?  Can anyone recommend how I can get the value `Lex` efficiently in a single line?

Comment: if you're using Ruby 2.3+ try `final_data.dig(*location)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Hash#dig to Specify Keys at Runtime

An easy way to drill down into a dynamic list of key objects is to use Ruby's [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method. For example:

```rb
require 'json'

json = <<~'JSON'
  {
    "EmployeeName": {
      "FirstName": "Lex",
      "LastName": "Sharma"
    }
  }
JSON

# the path/query elements
keys = ['EmployeeName', 'FirstName']

# splat the array to turn array elements
# into positional arguments for Hash#dig
JSON.parse(json).dig *keys
#=> "Lex"
```

There are certainly other ways to navigate a Hash, but the #dig method allows you to chain keys as a list of arguments, rather than hard-coding the number of keys as you would need to do with a series of [element reference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) calls like `json[key1][key2]`.